# Assign more tham one validation class to cutom Hibernate validation constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I created custom Hibernate class-level Validator

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {
        validatorA.class,
        validatorB.class
})

public @interface ValidVar {
    String message() default "invalid";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and annotate class with it

```
@ValidVar
public class SiteVar
```

The problem is it does not work, it just skip validation.

if in

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {
        validatorA.class,
        validatorB.class
})
```

I am using single class @Constraint(validatedBy = validatorA.class) it works.

How do I specify multi validators?